# VC++ 10 complains that a lot of types are not defined, C99

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010

I'm trying to compile an open source project I downloaded which was apparently written in VC++ 7.1.

After a lot of trouble, being a novice at C++, I managed to download and fix includes for STLPort that the project uses. However, I get something like 15,000 errors complaining that certain types are not defined. A few of them are:

```
u_int32_t
int64_t
u_int16_t
u_int8_t
```

After a bit of Googling, I figured out they are added in C99. Other developers before me have managed to compile it using VC. I'm using VC 10 though.

The project has been dead for a few years, so I cannot contact the author.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Visual C++ compiler does not support most C99 features.

If you want to use the standard fixed-width integer types, you need to make sure you include `<cstdint>` and qualify them with `std::` or include `<stdint.h>`.

The standard fixed-width unsigned type names are `uint32_t`, `uint16_t`, and `uint8_t` (that is, there is no `_` between the `u` and `int`).  You can, of course, typedef your own types if you want to (while you should use the standard typedefs for new code, you may need to typedef your own to interoperate with legacy code).

Comment: Or use boost/cstdint, although it's easy enough to get hold of a version of plain `stdint.h` for Windows, if MSVC still doesn't include one.

Comment: What is the easiest way to make these typedefs extend to all source/header files?

Comment: @Steve:  The standard library shipped with Visual C++ 2010 includes `<cstdint>`.

Comment: @James: oh good. Took their time, but got there eventually :-)

Comment: @Max:  Create a header with all of these typedefs in it and include that header in all the files that need it.  If you don't want to modify the files, you can define the types as macros on the command line (that's messier, but allows you not to have to edit the files).

Comment: Just to keep in mind (you know, in case there's a major CPU architecture revolution at some point ;p): The `intN_t` and `uintN_t` typedefs aren't guaranteed to exist, but the `intNleast_t` and `uintNleast_t` are.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty easy to define these types for yourself in Visual Studio, since they offer __int(bitsize) functionality.

```
typedef __int64 int64_t;
typedef unsigned __int32 u_int32_t;
typedef unsigned __int16 u_int16_t;
typedef unsigned __int8 u_int8_t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a compatible C99 compiler and libraries, and the point the VC++10 environment at those.

However I suspect the easier way to find the build/make files and use those.

Comment: What would be a sufficient compiler compatible with VC 10?